# Android Satellite Map View with out Road/City/Country label

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, android-mapview, android-maps

I want to display Satellite Map view in Android without Road/city/country label overlapped on it. Which is by default in Android how can I do this.

I want to show both view shown in Picture. I am able to show hybrid view but not Satellite view.

[image]

Comment: But Before that i was using onTap(int index) so instead of that i have to use this onTap(GeoPoint p , MapView mapView)  method or i have to use both ? can u please tell me

Comment: can you please provide me some link or some sample code so that i can use it as a refrence if possible ..thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are referring to towns, buildings, cities, street name labels, there is no API in Android to disable labels, but might be in future they realize to include in API, You never know. We do have another options to do that for example using Javascript MAP API [Google Maps JavaScript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes i also considered this but in the end i found the solution for the same i used mapquest api to achieve this it provides all the view. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ..

MapView map =(MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);

map.setSatellite(true);

Answer (score 0):

If you use Google maps android api v2 you can do this:

```
GoogleMap map;
...
// Satellite photograph data. Road and feature labels are not visible.
map.setMapType(GoogleMap.Satellite);
```

[documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#map_types)